# PayPal Parameters for Item Detail, Sales Tax and Shipping in Adaptive Payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, activemerchant, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a Rails (3.0, Ruby 1.9.2) app I'm building where visitors are able to buy things from my users (with the payment going directly from buyer to user).  I'm trying to use PayPal Adaptive Payments to make this happen, however, what I can't figure out is how I can:

1. make the description (top line in PayPal) = product name in my app.  Right now, I can sent the payment, but the top line, which normally describes the item someone is buying in PayPal shows as the recipients email and I don't know how to change that
2. show shipping and sales tax separate from the main amount

I've tried:

1. [reviewing PayPal's documentation on Adaptive Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPayAPI)
2. posting to the PayPal developer boards
3. trying Apigee to see if that revealed anything to me

Here's my current code:

```
 gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalAdaptivePaymentGateway.new( :login => "foo",:password => "bar", :signature => "foobar",:appl_id => "foobar1" )

  ss= gateway.pay amount.to_i, @user.paypal_account,
    :ip => request.remote_ip,
    :sender_email => params[:paypal_email],
    :return_url =>"http://#{current_subdomain}.foobar.com/product/#{params[:product_id]}",
    :cancel_url => request.referer,
    :client_details =>
    {
    :application_id => '60',
    :customer_type => 'user',
    :customer_id => '12',
    :tracking_id => tracking_id,
    :pay_key => '24',
    :ipn_notification_url => "http://foobar.com/paypal_ipn"
    }
```

The code works for getting the payment info, it mainly doesn't display like I want it to (the item name/description shows as the recipient, @user.paypal_account - and i'd like to break down the amount if possible to show shipping and tax).

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Payments doesn't support this in the regular checkout pages.

Comment: is there another paypal api i could use where i dictate the receiver (as a third party), but receive the ipn?

Comment: Depends. How many receivers would typically have? Do you require chained payments, or is parallel payments fine as well?

Comment: receivers will always be one.  i'm just trying to allow a visitor pay a third party, but i need to receive an ipn

Comment: In that case you could just go with PayPal Express Checkout and send the receiver's email address in the SUBJECT variable. The receiver would need to grant you permission to call an API on their behalf though. Ping me via mail if you want me to walk you through it; ppmtsrob@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code (I'm using paypal_adaptive gem)

I specified a few more parameters and it may vary since you are using ActiveMerchant's paypal classes:

```
pay_request = PaypalAdaptive::Request.new

server="http://mybaseurl.com"
data = {
  "returnUrl" => "#{server}/sales/summary?sale_id=#{sale_id}", 
  "requestEnvelope" => {"errorLanguage" => "en_US"},
  "currencyCode"=>"USD",  
  "receiverList"=>{"receiver"=>[{"email"=>"#{@sale.seller.email}","amount"=>"item amount"}]},
  "cancelUrl"=>"#{server}/payments/canceled_payment_request?sale_id=#{sale_id}",
  "actionType"=>"PAY",
  "ipnNotificationUrl"=>"#{server}/payments/ipn_notification",
  "feesPayer"=>"EACHRECEIVER",
  "memo"=>"Purchase for item from my company",
  "reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError"=>"true",
  "trackingID"=>"#{sale_id}",
  "partnerName"=>"Pretty sure this is the top line in paypal"
      }

@pay_response = pay_request.pay(data)
```

So, partnerName above is the top line that you can specify to be your app

As for sales tax, here's a long thread in the forums...I'm not sure about that one...maybe you have to set it in your paypal profile that you collect sales tax, or maybe calculate before getting the total you are asking the buyer for, and make it obvious to them on a summary screen. [forum thread](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/soap/sales-tax)

Also, here's more documentation that you may not have seen, since they organize half their docs on x.com and then some more on cms.paypal.com...https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation